# Execute different function when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I'm working on a webpage using Javascript and I want to implement a button so that whenever you click it the text inside the button change to the next text.

Currently I'm doing it like this (also a demo to illustrate what I mean):

[CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZeJQj)

```
var textCount = 0;
function changeText() {
  var myText = document.getElementById("demo");
  switch (textCount) {
    case 0:{
      myText.innerHTML = "This is the second text";
      textCount++;
    }
    break;
    case 1: {
      myText.innerHTML = "This is the third text";
      textCount++;
    }
    break;
    case 2: {
      myText.innerHTML = "It keeps going on like this";
      textCount++;
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Basically I use the **switch statement** and a counter to go step by step.

Another way I can think of to do this is by having an **array** that holds all the text and my function just go through it (seems more efficient)

---

- But I still want to know if there is any other way out there (though obvious) that you can achieve this with pure Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your code works, this question is more suited for the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks but I think I got an answer I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you can make it cleaner & more efficient by using an array, for example:

```
let list = ['Message one', 'Message two', 'Message three', 'Message four'];

let counter = 0;

function clickHandler () {
    element.textContent = list[counter];
    counter = (counter + 1) % list.length; // If you want to loop messages, otherwise ++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @DanielD. You're welcome! Don't forget to accept it if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I marked it as accept, just one side question. What exactly does the `% list.length` do and how will it loop my list back ?

Comment: `%` is modulus. It'll give the remainder of division. For example, if `list.length=4` and `count` is at 2, `(count + 1) % 4` = 3, because the remainder of 3/4 is 3, but if you add one again, `(count + 1) % 4` = 0 because the remainder of 4/4 is 0.